# Android PhoneGap issue for Android 2.3.3

Tags: android, cordova

I have my HTML5 as following.

```
<ul id="toolsmenu"></ul>
```

In the JS file I have

```
$("#toolsmenu").append("<li><a href='#msglist'…..……. ></a></li>");
```

This works without problem on Android 4.2 emulator. But the list does not show up when I use Android 2.3.3. Can someone please tell me why is this?

Comment: Can someone please help me on this? Dpa99c's answer too works well on android 3.0 and above. But it is not working on Android 2.3.3. Is it JQuery or Cordova issue? Seriously stuck here. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android 4.x is more tolerant of HTML/JS syntax errors than 2.x so I'd suggest checking there's nothing else in your code that could be causing the issue.
The following test case worked for me on Android 2.3.4 - seems unlikely that 2.3.3 would behave differently.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.8.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function deviceready() {
            $("#toolsmenu").append("<li><a href='#msglist'>Message List</a></li>");
            var deviceInfo = 'Device Name: '     + device.name     + '<br />' +
                            'Device Cordova: '  + device.cordova + '<br />' +
                            'Device Platform: ' + device.platform + '<br />' +
                            'Device UUID: '     + device.uuid     + '<br />' +
                            'Device Model: '    + device.model     + '<br />' +
                            'Device Version: '  + device.version  + '<br />';

           $("#deviceProperties").html(deviceInfo);

        }
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", deviceready, true);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul id="toolsmenu"></ul>

        <p id="deviceProperties">Loading device properties...</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've put the Eclipse project and resulting APK [here](http://ge.tt/65eZJZj/v/0) - try downloading it and running it on your devices.

Here's a screenshot of it running on my HTC HD2 running Android 2.3.4:

[image: Test case running on my HTC HD2 running Android 2.3.4]